# How do I install soap extension?

Tags: php, soap, dreamhost

How do I install Soap?

I got this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in /home/user/mysite.com/path/to/file.php  on line 16

I am hosting my site in DreamHost and they don't support any third-party installation.

UPDATE:

I copied the php.ini file with this script: `http://sxi.sabrextreme.com/dh-phpini`

I am using an API from a website and it says something like this:

```
#######################################################################
## You need to enable the following extensions in your PHP.ini file  ##
## php_openssl.dll          ##
## php_soap.dll             ##
#######################################################################
```

and here are the list of extensions my php.ini file has:

```
extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_cpdf.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
;extension=php_dbase.dll
;extension=php_dbx.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll
;extension=php_fdf.dll
;extension=php_filepro.dll
;extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_ifx.dll
;extension=php_iisfunc.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_java.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_mcrypt.dll
;extension=php_mhash.dll
;extension=php_mime_magic.dll
;extension=php_ming.dll
;extension=php_mssql.dll
;extension=php_msql.dll
;extension=php_mysql.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll
**extension=php_openssl.dll**
;extension=php_oracle.dll
;extension=php_pdf.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
;extension=php_snmp.dll
;extension=php_sockets.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
;extension=php_w32api.dll
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
;extension=php_yaz.dll
;extension=php_zip.dll
```

The problem is, the extension php_soap.dll is not found there.

Comment: Yes. Move away from Dreamhost.

Comment: actually, I don't own the site :(

Comment: @neo: they arent that bad if its not a mission critical site.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

## For Windows

1. Find `extension=php_soap.dll` or `extension=soap` in *php.ini* and remove the commenting semicolon at the beginning of the line. Eventually check for `soap.ini` under the *conf.d* directory.
2. Restart your server.

## For Linux

### Ubuntu:

#### PHP7

*Apache*

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-soap 
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

**PHP5**

```
sudo apt-get install php-soap
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

### OpenSuse:

#### PHP7

*Apache*

```
sudo zypper in php7-soap
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

*Nginx*

```
sudo zypper in php7-soap
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: For **OpenSuse** users: one should use `sudo zypper install php7.0-soap`; however it is needed to provide the correct repositories (`sudo zypper repos` / `sudo zypper addrepo` according to https://en.opensuse.org/Package_repositories) in order to retrieve PHP extensions.

Comment: @Kamafeather, how can I add the repo?

Comment: Read again, I wrote the commands. The correct repo to use depends on Opensuse version and PHP version installed. Check the "devel repository"(https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/php:/) and the "Wiki - Additional repositories"(https://en.opensuse.org/Additional_package_repositories).

Comment: If you use *XAMPP* on WIN10 there is `extension=soap` instead `extension=php_soap.dll` in `php.ini`. Just uncomment and it will work after restarting apache

Comment: Thx alot this helped with with php version 7.4

Comment: For php 8.1 : sudo apt-get install php8.1-soap

Comment: @NomanJaved "E: Unable to locate package php8.1-soap" on ubunto

Comment: For Kubernetes : /etc/init.d/apache2 reload, ie https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523338/how-to-restart-apache2-without-terminating-docker-container

Answer (score 57):

In **ubuntu** to install `php_soap` on **PHP7** use below commands. [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/soap.installation.php)

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-soap
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

For older version of php use below command and restart apache.

```
apt-get install php-soap
```

Answer (score 18):

find this line in php.ini :

```
;extension=soap
```

then remove the semicolon `;` and restart Apache server

Answer (score 6):

In Ubuntu with php7.3:

```
sudo apt install php7.3-soap 
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 4):

Please follow the below steps :

```
 1) Locate php.ini in your apache bin folder, I.e Apache/bin/php.ini
 2) Remove the ; from the beginning of extension=php_soap.dll
 3) Restart your Apache server (by using : 
    # /etc/init.d/apache2 restart OR 
    $ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart OR 
    $ sudo service apache2 restart)
 4) Look up your phpinfo();

 you may check here as well,if this does not solve your issue:  
 https://www.php.net/manual/en/soap.requirements.php
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, there was no extension=php_soap.dll in my php.ini
But this was because I had copied the php.ini from a old and previous php version (not a good idea).
I found the dll in the ext directory so I just could put it myself into the php.ini
extension=php_soap.dll
After Apache restart all worked with soap :)

Answer (score 2):

How To for Linux Ubuntu...

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-soap
```

Check if file `php_soap.ao` exists on `/usr/lib/php/20160303/`

```
ls /usr/lib/php/20160303/ | grep -i soap
soap.so
php_soap.so
```

```
sudo vi /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
```

Change the line :

`;extension=php_soap.dll`

to

`extension=php_soap.so`

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

CHecking...

```
php -m | more
```

Answer (score 1):

Dreamhost now includes SoapClient in their PHP 5.3 builds.  You can switch your version of php in the domain setup section of the dreamhost control panel.

Answer (score 0):

They dont support it as in in they wont help you or be responsible for you hosing anything, but you can install custom extensions. To do so you need to first [set up a local install of php 5](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Advanced_PHP_configuration), during that process you can compile in extensions you need or you can add them dynamically to the php.ini after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu+php 5.6+nginx I used

```
sudo apt install php5.6-soap
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo systemctl restart php5.6-fpm.service
```

Only after that it started to work.