# Set-up PHP SOAP Extension in Windows

Tags: php, soap

I'm having a lot of confusions on how to set up PHP SOAP extension in windows based on what's on the net.

Could you please help me, how would I be able to do it?

Any suggested references?

Comment: I still haven't tried anything since I'm confused where I suppose to start.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Referring to the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php#install.windows.extensions.overview), all you need to do is:

1. Locate your `php.ini` file. This is normally under your `<php_home>` folder (for example, `C:/PHP5`).
2. Search for and uncomment the line that says `;extension=php_soap.dll`, by removing the first `;` character, to make it looks like `extension=php_soap.dll`
3. Then restart your server.

Note that the `php_soap.dll` is included in the default PHP5 distribution, and you can find it under the `<php_home>/ext` folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't see any line in the file that says `;extension=php_soap.dll`

Comment: It should be there by default. If not, just add `extension=php_soap.dll` to the file. And make sure `php_soap.dll` exists under the `ext` folder. Then restart your server.

Comment: I removed; and restart apache but still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

1: Find `extension=php_soap.dll` in **php.ini** and remove the semicolon(**;**)

2: Restart your Server

Reference : [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509143/php-how-do-i-install-soap-extension/22397686#22397686)

Answer (score 4):

1. open php.ini file in your text editor.
2. Find
   `;extension=soap`
3. Remove `;`
4. Save changes
5. Start the server again.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on PHP 5.6.33 nts x64. Open php.ini from PHP install-dir eg. C:/PHP5633-nts_x64/php-ini. I'm using the development version.

1. Uncomment "extension_dir" option, use the "on Windows" option. eg.

> ;extension_dir = "ext"

2. Uncomment

> ;extension=php_soap.dll

3. Restart server