# how to restart container instead of deleting pod and recreate?

Tags: apache, docker, kubernetes, moodle

There are cases when you want to restart a specific container instead of deleting the pod and letting Kubernetes recreate it.

i am having one pod running apache container. i did editing in apache config file. for SSL certificate virtual host port changes etc.

now i want to restart apache2 service but without recreating pod.

i tried inside pod with

```
service apache2 restart
```

but it also recreate pod and configuration also change again.

Comment: When?  The standard approach IME is to delete the troublesome pod; one of the other replicas can pick up the load, and the new pod will start in a clean state.

Comment: i am using someone image form docker hub. so i am manually installing ssl cert inside pod..so on Apache restart  pod recreation also happen. that is the what problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how it supposed to work.

You should not change anything inside the `POD`.
If your `POD` dies or crushes, Kubernetes should just start a new one and everything should work.
Also keep in mind that you cannot scale the `POD` that had configuration altered.

Please check the Kubernetes docs [Configure a Pod to Use a ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/)

You can use `ConfigMap` to create configuration file.

> ConfigMaps allow you to decouple configuration artifacts from image content to keep containerized applications portable. This page provides a series of usage examples demonstrating how to create ConfigMaps and configure Pods using data stored in ConfigMaps.

`ConfigMap` can be created and read a content of a file :

`$ kubectl create configmap config_data --from-file=config_data.txt`

or it can be declared in .yml

```
config_map:
  data: 
    db_name=colors_db
    table_name=purple
  name: config_data
  version: v1
```

Also this might be done by creating a `secret`
or `secret` can be declared:

```
secret:
  data:
    username: my-username
    password: my-password
  name: secret_data
  version: v1
```

I recommend reading [Kubernetes recipe: store nginx config with ConfigMap and reverse-proxy requests from your domain to your Github page](https://medium.com/@olegsmetanin/kubernetes-receipt-reverse-proxy-to-your-github-page-using-configmap-1b81ec31cbd1).

There are also other options like mounting path with needed configuration on new `POD`.
I advice you to check [Configure a Pod to Use a PersistentVolume for Storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/)

Comment: thankyou so much for reply. you are right not suppose to edit inside pod manually. i am using someone else docker image and installing ssl cert manually for testing. on apache restart pod recreation happen and all configuration change again. i just want to test https://

Comment: You can have a look at [Manage TLS Certificates in a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/)

Answer (score 1):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523338/how-to-restart-apache2-without-crashing-docker-container)

You can also create a new dockerfile for override the apache dockerfile and change de CMD line, but it's more complicated

Comment: docker file i can make but i am using sone one else docker image form docker hub

Comment: you can build your own docker image from already existing image and add layers on top of it.

Comment: ok i have to check it not that much experience i have. i was thinking to use volume mount for ssl certificate or shell script something that. then i will be automated at time of pod creation