# How to run test perl script as cgi script with httpd?

Tags: apache, docker, cgi, httpd.conf

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html) and run sample script under cgi.

Below are steps which I did:

1) Made sample script

```
$ cat > test.pl <<EOF
> #!/usr/bin/perl
> print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
> print "Hello, World.";
EOF
```

2) run httpd docker container and mounted created script as volume in cgi-bin directory:

```
$ docker run --name cgi_test --rm -p 3000:80 -v $(pwd)/test.pl:/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/test.pl httpd
```

3) check if CGI module is enabled:

```
$ docker exec -it cgi_test cat /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf | grep modules/mod_cgid.so
    #LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgid.so
```

CGI module was turned out so I enabled it:

```
$ docker exec -it cgi_test sed -i 's,#\(LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so\),\1,g' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

4) Checked `ScriptAlias` directive and enabling of `alias_module` :

```
$ docker exec -it cgi_test cat /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf | grep "ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/"
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/"
$ docker exec -it cgi_test httpd -M | grep -e cgid -e alias
 cgid_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
```

It was ok

5) Checked exec permissions:

```
$ docker exec -it cgi_test ls -la /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/test.pl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1000 76 Mar 20 12:41 /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/test.pl
```

It was ok

6) Restarted httpd in docker container:

```
$ docker kill --signal="USR1" cgi_test
```

But when I to to http://localhost:3000/cgi-bin/test.pl I see `503 Service Unavailable` and this error in log:

```
[Wed Mar 20 19:03:02.323430 2019] [cgid:error] [pid 1446:tid 139952364902144] (22)Invalid argument: [client 172.17.0.1:34328] AH01257: unable to connect to cgi daemon after multiple tries: /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/test.pl
```

What else I need to do to run script ?

Answer (score 2):

To run a script under CGI you don't need to change any file in the official `httpd` Docker image.

Make sure that your script is executable with a `chmod +x test.pl` and pass to the server program the `-c` option with the configuration directive to load the CGI module, as described in the following command:

```
docker run \
  -it \
  --rm \
  -p 127.0.0.1:8080:80 \
  -v $(pwd)/test.pl:/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/test.pl \
  httpd:alpine \
  httpd-foreground -c "LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so"
```

Some explanations:

- Alpine variant image is used because it's smaller than the default Debian based image and it's more than enough for our purposes
- `httpd-foreground` script is available in all official `httpd` images and it allows to execute Apache HTTP Server in foreground mode (it's equivalent to `httpd -D FOREGROUND`)
- publish option `-p` contains also the loopback IP address to prevent access to this test server from the outside

Answer (score 1):

To make everything work I was needed to restart `httpd` twice instead of once :

```
docker kill --signal="USR1" cgi_test  # (x2)
```

I thought maybe it's `USR1` signal (Graceful Restart) issue , but i had same with `HUP` signal (Restart Now). To apply changes I need to send signal twice. So looks like `httpd` container issue.

Comment: You are a genius... It took me lots of time until I saw your answer and ran `apachectl restart` TWICE in my container...