# The requested PHP extension ext-soap * is missing from your system when updating composer in Yii2

Tags: php, laravel, yii2, composer-php

```
Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-soap * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's soap extension.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for googleads/googleads-php-lib ^27.1 -> satisfiable by googleads/googleads-php-lib[27.1.0].
    - googleads/googleads-php-lib 27.1.0 requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Note: I have enabled the soap extension in php.ini

Comment: are you sure you are updating the correct ini file

Comment: yes, I have updated in xamp/php/php.ini(dev and prod both)

Comment: If you're using Linux, What's the output of `php -m | grep soap`

Comment: Please show the contents of your `php.ini` file and the output of `php --ini`, `php -m` and `php -i`.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509143/how-do-i-install-soap-extension/41518256) answer. Hope, it'll help.

Answer (score 1):

This command should fix it `sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl`.
Note: Change the PHP version to what you are using.

Comment: Why would installing the curl extension solve an error about the soap extension?