# Memory exhausted and PHP Version mismatch errors. Not able to install image intervention laravel 5.5 package

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php, intervention

I want to change color of my image. So I'm trying to use image/intervention of laravel.
Followed their documentation:
http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation
https://packagist.org/packages/intervention/image

When i tried the following, i got an memory exhausted error:

## 1. composer require intervention/image

Error:
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.
E:\xampp\htdocs\Myproject>php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
512M

So, i followed the below link and increased to memory_limit=-1 from memory_limit=512M
https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors

Now, again tried this command composer require intervention/image. Now i got a different error:

Error:
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - This package requires php ~7.2.0 but your PHP version (7.3.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - mpociot/vat-calculator dev-master requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.
    - mpociot/vat-calculator dev-master requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.
    - mpociot/vat-calculator dev-master requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for mpociot/vat-calculator dev-master -> satisfiable by mpociot/vat-calculator[dev-master].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - E:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Why am i getting these errors? **How can i install image/intervention package** in my application?
**I'm using laravel 5.5 , PHP 7.3.11**

As the error says, **do i have to install 7.2.0 php version**? Or is there any other solutions?

Comment: Hi, the first problem seems to mean that you have a dependency on `PHP` in `your` composer.json. Maybe you need to update it.

The second problem is because you are missing `soap` extension in PHP. Try to install it. This [question/anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22397686/6410457) could help you.

Comment: @GrenierJ, I enabled soap extension as given in that link. Soap error is gone now. How can i find which dependency needs a update? does composer diagnose command help in this?

Comment: I think you have something like `"php": "~7.2",` in your `composer.json`

Comment: @GrenierJ, But, i'm still getting this error " **Problem 1
    - This package requires php ~7.2.0 but your PHP version (7.3.11) does not satisfy that requirement.** "

Comment: @GrenierJ, yes i have "php": "~7.2.0"  in composer file

Comment: So you need to change it to `^7.2` to allow all versions of PHP upper than `7.2`. And run `composer update php`.

Comment: @GrenierJ, i changed "php": "~7.2.0" to "php": "~7.3.0", & ran the composer require intervention/image command. It is installed now with these warnings
**Package blackfyre/json-ld is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use blackfyre/json-ld instead.
Package mtdowling/cron-expression is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use dragonmantank/cron-expression instead.
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package roumen/sitemap is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laravelium/sitemap instead.** can i ignore this?

Comment: Yes you can ignore this. It's only you have some dependencies that use abandonned dependencies ( maybe update them). Whit `composer depends --tree <dependecyName>` you can see why this dependency is needed and maybe try to update parent dependeny.

Comment: @GrenierJ, great!! thank you for all your responses. please post this so that i can mark as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem come because there is something like `"php": "~7.2"`, in your `composer.json`. Change to `"php": ^7.2"` to allow all PHP minor version upper 7.2. Run `composer update php` to fix `composer.lock`

The second problem is because you are missing soap extension in PHP. Try to install it. This [question/anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509143/how-do-i-install-soap-extension/22397686#22397686) could help you.