# Cannot install soap on wordpress on azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, woocommerce, soap

I want to install a plug that requires SoapClient.
In WooCommerce -> Status I have message like that *"Your server does not have the SoapClient class enabled - some gateway plugins which use SOAP may not work as expected."*

I spent a lot of time on it trying several ways:

**1. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/18ddb045-05ed-4ad3-aafa-a2c872ece55e/install-soap-module-for-php-72-in-web-app-for-containers-wordpress?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview**

In Azure SCM Kudu -> SSH

[image]

Later I reset the server using azure and still not working.

[image]

When I perform this action twice I get this message, but when I do a reset I can install it again.
[image]

**2. [How do I install soap extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509143/how-do-i-install-soap-extension)**

In  Azure SCM Kudu -> SSH

I cannot use sudo and apt-get
[image]
[image]

I also can't understand why I don't have root on ssh. In many examples, people have something like root@ASFF1234. I have only ASFF1234. :(

In Azure SCM Kudu -> Bash

I cannot use sudo and apt-get doesnt work.
[image]
[image]

**3. https://bobcares.com/blog/woocommerce-soap-client/**

*yum* doesn't work on SSH and bash

Would someone be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install soap extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509143/how-do-i-install-soap-extension) I think this is what you need - no need for a global SOAP installation.

Comment: But i cannot use sudo and apt-get on my azure web service :(

Comment: Sudo is not needed, I think. Have you tried it without sudo? It will just be installed for your user instead.

Comment: when i user only apt-get i have permission danied